# JSONSerializer for different json object

Tags: json, swift

I have different type of dataset in the given json.

**Courses json**

```
{"name" : "University of Florida", 
 "data": {"GivenCourse" :{"name" : "Introduction to Computer Science", "tuition": 3000}}, 
 "type" : "Courses" }
```

**Professors json**

```
{"name" : "University of Florida", 
 "data": {"Professor" :{"name" : "Dr.Francis Tudeluv", "age" :53}}, 
 "type" : "Professor" }
```

I could able to write two structs, one is for Professor and the other one is Courses. However, as you see there are several common elements in the json object except the `data`. How that could be better handled?

Courses Struct is as follows:

```
struct Courses: Codable {
    let name: String
    let data: DataClass
    let type: String
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let givenCourse: GivenCourse

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case givenCourse = "GivenCourse"
    }
}

// MARK: - GivenCourse
struct GivenCourse: Codable {
    let name: String
    let tuition: Int
}
```

**Professors Class**

```
// MARK: - Welcome
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let name: String
    let data: DataClass
    let type: String
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let professor: Professor

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case professor = "Professor"
    }
}

// MARK: - Professor
struct Professor: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to declare `DataClass` as enum with associated types

```
enum DataClass {
    case course(Course), professor(Professor)
}
```

and `Type` as decodable enum

```
enum Type : String, Decodable {
    case courses = "Courses", professor = "Professor"
}
```

Then implement `init(from decoder` and decode the different types depending on the `type` value. The keys `GivenCourse` and `Professor` are ignored.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let data: DataClass
    let type: Type
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name, data, type }
    
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.type = try container.decode(Type.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
            case .courses: let courseData = try container.decode([String:Course].self, forKey: .data)
            data = .course(courseData.values.first!)
            case .professor: let professorData = try container.decode([String:Professor].self, forKey: .data)
            data = .professor(professorData.values.first!)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Professor
struct Professor: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

// MARK: - Course
struct Course: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let tuition: Int
}
```

---

```
let jsonString = """
{"name" : "University of Florida",
"data": {"GivenCourse" :{"name" : "Introduction to Computer Science", "tuition": 3000}},
"type" : "Courses" }
"""

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using generic and manual encode/decode:

```
struct MyDataContainer<T: Codable>: Codable {
    let name: String
    let data: T
    let type: String
}

struct Professor: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

enum DataKind {
    case unknown
    case professor(Professor)
    case givenCourse(GivenCourse)
}

struct GivenCourse: Codable {
    let name: String
    let tuition: Int
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let dataKind: DataKind

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case professor = "Professor"
        case givenCourse = "GivenCourse"
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if values.contains(.givenCourse) {
            let course = try values.decode(GivenCourse.self, forKey: .givenCourse)
            dataKind = .givenCourse(course)
        } else if values.contains(.professor) {
            let professor = try values.decode(Professor.self, forKey: .professor)
            dataKind = .professor(professor)
        } else {
            dataKind = .unknown
        }
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch dataKind {
        case .givenCourse(let course):
            try container.encode(course, forKey: .givenCourse)
        case .professor(let professor):
            try container.encode(professor, forKey: .professor)
        case .unknown: break
        }
    }
}
```

`MyDataContainer<DataClass>`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply include both *Optional* `givenCourse` and `professor` models in your `DataClass`. Each possible model will be decoded thanks to the *Codable* protocol.

**Edit `DataClass`:**

```
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let givenCourse: GivenCourse?
    let professor: Professor?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case givenCourse = "GivenCourse"
        case professor = "Professor"
    }
}
```

**Use/Debug:**

```
let decodedData = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
        
if decodedData.type == "Professor" {
    print(decodedData.data.professor)
} else if  decodedData.type == "Courses" {
    print(decodedData.data.givenCourse)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the possible types of "data" will remain fairly small, I would just use optionals for each possible type as concrete members of DataClass, with the CodingKeys fully specified, like so:

```
struct Professor: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}

struct GivenCourse: Codable {
    let name: String
    let tuition: Int
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    var professor: Professor?
    var givenCourse: GivenCourse?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case givenCourse = "GivenCourse"
        case professor = "Professor"
    }
}

struct SchoolData: Codable {
    let name: String
    let data: DataClass
}
```

This will correctly parse the two JSON samples you have, leaving the unused type nil in the DataClass. You could add some computed variables to DataClass if you like for convenient semantics, for example

```
var isProfessor: Bool {
    get {
        return nil != self.professor
    }
}
```

This structure also lets you handle the case (if it's possible) of a record having both course and professor data - the DataClass will be able to parse both in one JSON record if it finds it.